# Reset jquery tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, javascript-framework, jquery-tabs

I'm using jquery ui tab version 1.9.1 and I do have content with scroller in second tab. What I'm trying to do is whenever I come back on second tab, tab should be reset(Should display content from top).

I've tried to find solution but what I got is to reset form fields on tabs and indexes not for this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

Given you haven't provided any of your code it is difficult to guess, but if you are loading your tab content via. ajax, at the bottom of your HTML for your second tab, you could add a script like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#secondTabID').animate({scrollTop:$('#secondTabID').offset().top}, 'slow');
});
```

If your HTML is static, then you can probably do something with the [`activate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate) function.

Something like:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({

    activate: function(event, ui) {

       ui.newTab.animate({scrollTop:ui.newTab.offset().top}, 'slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Daren, Thanks for your response. At which event I should set this function? I mean is there any default property / event to define tab change?

Comment: Hi Dhaval - I have updated my post so that you can see I take care of both cases - remote tab load via. ajax and static HTML tab load.

Comment: Hi Daren, Thanks for updating your code to give me more clear idea. In your code tab will scroll up to the top but is there any way to reset that tab completely as I do have video on second tab so I need to reset that video too. I'm using videojs plugin to play the video, you can find that plugin here http://videojs.com/

Comment: If you loaded the tab remotely it would automatically "reset".  Here's an example on the jqueryui site:
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax